# cant call function in another dojo module from dojo module

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm having trouble calling a method from my dojo module in another dojo module.  The code of my calling module is:

```
define([
"Templates/MarkTicket",
"DataTypes/MarkTicketForm_Data",
"DBCalls/MarkTicketDB",
...], function (MarkTicket, MarkTicketForm_Data, MarkTicketDB, ...
) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {


        postCreate: function () {
            //both modules have Test Method
            MarkTicketDB.Test("call from MarkTicketForm");//works great
            MarkTicket.Test("call from MarkTicketForm");//object doesnt support property or method test

        },
...

    });
});
```

The call to Test in MarkTicketDB works just fine, but I get the error shown in the code comment when I try to call Test method in MarkTicket.  MarkTicket only shows a Createsubclass and extend method when I debug.  The module I'm calling these methods from is also located in the Templates directory -- could this be the problem?  (I've also tried defining Templates/MarkTicket as just MarkTicket in the define statement)The Templates package is defined in my main page

Any ideas?

Thanks

As I said in my comment I think the problem may be that my calling module (MarkTicketForm) is a dijit dialog that is instantiated and opened through MarkTicket here is the code:

MarkTicket:

```
...
postCreate: function () {
MT = new MarkTicketForm();//instaniate MarkTicketForm inside MarkTicket
}

...
//call a Method in MarkTicket Form to open the dialog
 MT.showForm(TicketInfo);
...
```

MarkTicketForm (code to show dialog):

```
...
showForm: function (ticketInfo) {
            ID = ticketInfo.ID;
            var DateRcvd = this.formatDate(ticketInfo.DateRcvd);
            this.lblID.innerHTML = ticketInfo.ID;
            this.lblTicket.innerHTML = ticketInfo.Ticket;
            this.lblRcvd.innerHTML = DateRcvd;
            this.lblType.innerHTML = ticketInfo.TicketType;
            this.myDialog.show();

        },
...
```

Comment: It's not because MarkTicket is in the Templates directory.  I can call methods in other modules in the Templates directory from my calling module.  MarkTicketForm (my calling module) is a dijit dialog that is opened from MarkTicket module -- maybe that has something to do with it.  The fact that MarkTicket shows createSubClass and extend methods when I debug maybe means it is a parent to my calling class?

Comment: Without the MarkTicket code it will be impossible to know what the cause is.

Answer (score 0):

Like g00glen00b said, you should have listed the code for MarkTicket.  However, since you said that:

> MarkTicket only shows a Createsubclass and extend method when I debug.

...it's clear that MarkTicket is a class created through dojo.declare().

Presumably Test() is an method on MarkTicket instances, not on the MarkTicket class itself.  Therefore, you could do something like this:

```
var m = new MarkTicket();
m.Test("call from MarkTicketForm");
```